TOUCH-PAD AND NETWORK DRIVERS ISSUE IN 22.04.05
when i install Ubuntu OS 22.04.05 version after all installation completed touch-pad and network drivers are not coming with in the OS and i am unable to install that drivers

You mention a release, but not which product (Server? Desktop? a flavor? etc) as they have different kernels as default (drivers are kernel modules; thus kernel matters), and you've not said what you actually tried..  eg. you mention you're unable to install drivers; so does that mean you tried ubuntu-drivers autoinstall in which case what output did you get from that command. What hardware are you trying to get working (specifically; ie. what touchpad are you using, what network chipset for wifi/ethernet etc) as we're limited to details you provide.

Please try 24.04 or 24.10 instead. New versions of Ubuntu have better support for new hardware

Also, we need hardware details. Please edit the question appropriately

my laptop is LENOVO THINKPAD ULTRA 5 & LENOVO THINKPAD T-SERIES
